# problems with printing 2d array from print function

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fill and print with 2d array, yet every time I try to compile it
says undeclared identifier c. And points an arrow at the c in the print function.
I tried declaring it many ways yet for some reason it will not work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(char x[][c], int r)
{
    for(int r  = 0; r < 25; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 25; c++)
        {
          cout << x[r][c]; 
        } 
        cout << endl;    
    } 
}

int main()
{
    void print(char x[][c], int r);

    char p[25][25];

    for(int r = 0; r < 25; r++)
    {

        for(int c = 0; c < 25; c++)
        {
            if(r==0)p[r][c]='x';
            else    p[r][c]='o';
        }    
    }   

    print(p[25][25]);


    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier `c`

Comment: what is c??
void print(char x[][c], int r) ??
and in this line
 void print(char x[][c], int r);

Comment: What means char x[][c]? Particularly "c"? Try to understand compiler error.

Comment: You haven't declared c. What is it?

Comment: Your code is wrong on so many levels... What do you want to achieve? Could you write the output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the following way

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


const size_t ROWS = 25;
const size_t COLS = 25;

void print(char x[][COLS], size_t r )
{
    for ( size_t i  = 0; i < r; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < COLS; j++ )
        {
          cout << x[i][j]; 
        } 
        cout << endl;    
    } 
}

int main()
{
    char p[ROWS][COLS];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < COLS; j++ )
        {
            if ( i == 0 ) p[i][j] = 'x';
            else p[i][j] = 'o';
        }    
    }   

    print( p, ROWS );


    return(0);
}
```

Another approach is to define the function the following way

```
void print( char ( &x )[ROWS][COLS] )
{
    for ( size_t i  = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < COLS; j++ )
        {
          cout << x[i][j]; 
        } 
        cout << endl;    
    } 
}
```

and call it like

```
    print( p );
```

Comment: can you explain another approach ? I don't know `char ( &x )[ROWS][COLS]`

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname  It is a declaration of a reference to a 2D array. For example if you have a declaration int x = 10; then a reference to x is declared like int &rx = x; If you have a 1D array int a[10]; then a reference to the array is declared like int ( &ra )[10] = a;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(char x[25][25])
{
    for(int r  = 0; r < 25; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 25; c++)
        {
          cout << x[r][c]; 
        } 
        cout << endl;    
    } 
}

int main()
{
    char p[25][25];

    for(int r = 0; r < 25; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 25; c++)
        {
            if(r==0)p[r][c]='x';
            else    p[r][c]='o';
        }    
    }   

    print(p);

    return(0);
}
```